# WiX: run MSI file without reference to version number

Tags: wix, windows-installer, version

I have a WiX Burn project, and I would like one of the MSI files to be ran every time, without reference to the version number.

To be more specific, let's say that I have **MSI A**, **MSI B**, and **MSI C**.

When I push out updates to the project (I'm using Major Updates because that seems easier than complicated patches and things of that nature), I would like:

- **MSI A** to install *if-and-only-if* its version number is greater than the version number on the target machine.
- **MSI B** to run *if-and-only-if* its version number is greater than the version number on the target machine.

  (So far, this is great, because that's exactly how Windows Installer works.)
- Finally, **MSI C** to run *every. single. time*.  No matter what.

Things I could try:

I could just make sure that its version number gets larger and larger for every build, but what if I get hit by a bus?  This installer may last a while.

I could bind the version number of one of the executables to MSI C's version number, but what if the executable isn't updated in that specific roll out?  There are no executables being installed that are guaranteed to update with every roll out.

Is there, like, a way to convert the version number to an int then run a Custom Action that increments the int, then convert that back to the version number, or anything like that?

Or -- better yet -- a switch of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the major upgrade option to upgrade the installed package regardless of the version number.

```
    <MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
              AllowDowngrades="yes"/>
```

Alos,check the [REINSTALLMODE Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371182(v=vs.85).aspx) for overriding files.

Comment: Hey, the MajorUpgrade element -- that might be a good idea!  I'll check it out.  I don't know anything about those properties.  The MSDN page makes it look like you use them on the command line (what with the flags), but in WiX you use properties in the markup.  So that's confusing.